# Setting API rate limit on Python with ratelimit library

Tags: python, api

```
 from ratelimit import limits, RateLimitException, sleep_and_retry
 from backoff import on_exception, expo
 max_hit = 5
 period = 300
 @limits(calls=max_hit, period=period)
    def StashNotes(self):
         url = ("https://www.r10.net/")
         raw_data = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
         if raw_data.status_code != 200:
              raise Exception('API response: {}'.format(raw_data.status_code))
         else:
                ## some unnecessary things here ##
```

I am trying to limit the API rate with a max hit of 5 and period 300, so my requests.get will not hit any more than 5 times in 300 second period. @limits(calls=max_hit,period=period) doesn't work, and can't really figure out why.

Is there any other way to do this besides ratelimit library, or how to fix @limits decoration? Any kind of solution is appreciated, thanks.

`headers=headers` contains sensitive information but it doesn't matter anyway just 2 cookie values in it.

Comment: Yeah it is just not indented on stackoverflow.

Comment: what do you mean by `@limits(calls=max_hit,period=period)` doesn't work, didn't you get any exception after more than 5 calls?

Comment: No like it couldnt limit the request, request hit more than 5 times in every time I try.

Comment: but when I try to call this, I get `ratelimit.exception.RateLimitException: too many calls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It throws exceptions for me when I try to make more than 5 iterations of call on API, getting exception after 5 calls,

> ratelimit.exception.RateLimitException: too many calls

**Fullcode:**

```
from flask import Flask
from ratelimit import limits

max_hit = 5
period = 300

@limits(calls=max_hit, period=period)
def StashNotes():
    return "sany"

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return StashNotes()
```